# MonoDroid: Fragment.Instantiate ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a swipping tab view using the ActionBar in Mono for Android.

The adroid for eclipse plugin has this as a default project template and I have manage to convert it over, I am now trying to add the functionally to separate my fragments out.

When I try to run my project I get a ClassNotFoundException

Here is the code for the Fragment

```
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

namespace MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App.UI.Customers
{
    public  class HomeTab : Fragment
    {
        public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup viewGroup, Android.OS.Bundle p2)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my section adapter

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Java.Lang;

namespace MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App
{
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        public readonly IList<TabInfo> Tabs = new List<TabInfo>();
        private Bundle _bundle;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            : base(fm)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._bundle = savedInstanceState;

        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int i)
        {
            var args = new Bundle();
            var page = Fragment.Instantiate(this._context, typeof(HomeTab).FullName);
            //          var page = new HomeTab(); <<--- Work but nothing displayed as none of the create methods are run
            page.Arguments = args;
            return page;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return this.Tabs.Count; }
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int p0)
        {
            return new String(this.Tabs[p0].PageTitle);
        }

    }
}
```

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate fragment
>   MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App.UI.Customers.HomeTab: make sure class
>   name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
>   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod
>   (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00024] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.4-branch/9f7cbd60/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:767
>
> at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.Instantiate
>   (Android.Content.Context,string) [0x00034] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.4-branch/9f7cbd60/source/monodroid-bindings/Compatibility-v4/bindings/obj/platform-14/src/generated/Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.cs:624
>
> at MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App.SectionsPagerAdapter.GetItem (int)
>   [0x00007] in
>   c:\Projects\MobileCompanion\trunk\MobileCompanion.Android.App\SectionsPagerAdapter.cs:28
>
> at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter.n_GetItem_I
>   (intptr,intptr,int) [0x00008] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.4-branch/9f7cbd60/source/monodroid-bindings/Compatibility-v4/bindings/obj/platform-14/src/generated/Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter.cs:56
>
> at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.780b3637-f853-4d6e-8435-9c92bc6a9dd5 (intptr,intptr,int)
>
> --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
>
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
>   instantiate fragment
>   MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App.UI.Customers.HomeTab: make sure class
>   name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
>
> ```
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
>
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> mobilecompanion.androidos.app.SectionsPagerAdapter.n_getItem(Native
>   Method)
>
> ```
>   at
> ```
>
> mobilecompanion.androidos.app.SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(SectionsPagerAdapter.java:30)
>
> ```
>   at
> ```
>
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
>
> ```
>   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:692)
>
>   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:821)
>
>   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
>
>   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
>
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>
> ```
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
>
> ```
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
>
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>
> ```
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
>
> ```
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
>
> ```
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
>
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> ```
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   MobileCompanion.AndroidOS.App.UI.Customers.HomeTab
>
> ```
>   at
> ```
>
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>
> ```
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The namespace must be all lowercase for `Fragment.Instantiate` to work.  I believe this limitation is carried over from Java.

```
var page = Fragment.Instantiate(_activity, typeof(T).Namespace.ToLower() + "." +  
                                typeof(T).Name);
```

Comment: The namespace needs to be lowercase, but the class name itself needs to be in normal camel case. For example: var page = Fragment.Instantiate(_activity, typeof(T).Namespace.ToLower() + "." + typeof(T).Name);

Comment: DO NOT use this method any more. Instead use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17798431/10957

Answer (score 5):

The better answer is:

```
var page = Fragment.Instantiate (_activity, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(T).Name);
```

Comment: I recently just upgraded Xamarin and suddenly on already working code the lower casing solution stopped working.  I replaced that code with this, and I'm golden!

Comment: This is definitely the new best answer as latest Xamarin uses new name mangling for android.

`"name mangling scheme for Android Callable Wrappers" has been modified. This means that the generated Java type names for C# classes are different.`